# Monte Carlo with UCB applied to complex card game

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, upperbound

I'm trying to understand how the MCTS Algorithm works and how I would implement it in a card game to improve the AI engine.

I've read mcts.ai/ website and many papers about it, including one that shows some results about the successfulness of applying Monte Carlo Search with UCB in the AI for a Magic cards game, that is more or less what I need to do, however I'm having some trouble trying to understand some points and how to apply it so solve what I need. I'm also not that much experienced in maths so I become lost when the papers explain all that stuff with complicated formulas.

This is what I've came up with so far:

1. Given a game state (user hand in the game), determine which are all the possible legal plays that can be made then I would create a List of Nodes (one representing every play) as a property in the MCTSTree's root node with each one's result (score value?)
2. Simulate a complete (until the end) gameplay for each one of those legal plays with a random player and record the result in every node, whether the player has won or lost in order to have a full picture.

Here is where "I think" Monte Carlo + UCB should be applied:

1. Select the more promising play (node) using UCB recursively and in case its leaf, expand that node with all possible plays from its gameState.
2. Simulate *n* playouts from the selected node until a certain amount of time is reached.

   - At this stage I have some doubts... say I try a random playout given a list of possible playouts... what do I have to do with that first result in order to continue simulating? Should I make the tree grow then?
3. How do I backpropagate the results?

Then,

- Having in mind that as this is a complex cards game and I have so many possible moves... would it has a good-enough performance to have so many childs in any node?
- If every simulation is based on a gamestate and the game is changing the state every time a player applies a movement then how can I know if the tree is really useful?

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: This survey paper (from March 2012) lays out the core MCTS framework and then discusses many variants: http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~sgc/papers/browne_ieee12.pdf It includes details on calculating UCB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MCTS is just the following:

[image]

I describe it a bit differently than what the image suggests, which might be more ready for implementation.

1. Descent from your root node (the current state of the game), using *UCB* at each step until you decide upon an **uninstantiated** node `l`. (Select)
2. Add `l` to your tree. (Expand)
3. From `l`, play a random game. (Simulate)
4. Update all the nodes on the path from `l` back to the root node with the result of the playout.
5. Repeat until time runs out.

If your branching factor is large, as you mentioned, you might need to consider other strategies for selecting a successor while descending the tree, like RAVE.

Comment: About the point 2: from leaf l's gamestate I obtain all the possible plays and play a random game for each one of them, am I right? And this is what would define how large is my branching factor. Correct me if i'm wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @magnoz *A)* No, you only play *one* random game, which goes through exactly one of the possible successors of `l`. The first move of this random game gets added as a new leaf below `l` (sorry, forgot that part). Then you start again at 1. *B)* The branching factor is the number of possible moves at each state (usually this varies, so you think about the average branching factor).

Comment: Ok, I think i got it, now.. as you described the process, you executes first the simulation and then the expansion, am i right?

Comment: @magnoz Well, looking at it again, I changed the order of my description again and made it a bit more precise. It seems to be better to think about the expansion happening before the simulation. Point is, then the new child gets selected by UCT and not by the random playout (which makes a difference when the child has instantiated siblings). So basically what I have changed is: Descent does not select a leaf but an uninstantiated node form which the simulation is run.

Comment: Btw, you simulate only one game in case you have only one child, right? If you have more childs you may simulate them in two parallel threads (?) and just one more thing, you do expand the tree ONLY with the simulation's first action? or do you add a child for each possibility as well? as described in one paper: "Expansion: One (or more) child nodes are added to expand the tree, according to the available actions."

Comment: @magnoz Well, there is no right or wrong here. You can run multiple simulations per loop for  the selected node if you like. You can also expand all successors of a node and run simulations for each one. When I think of vanilla MCTS+UCT, I think of running one simulation per loop and adding one node per loop (which is the first move of the playout that's not already inside the tree).

Comment: thank you so much! just one more thing, what would it be in practice an uninstanciated node? by that you mean that you select a NEW child of the leaf node to which UCB has been arrived?

Comment: @magnoz Your game **defines** a (rather big) tree, of which you can only explore a small portion (for most games). Instantiating a node means that you take a node from this big, virtual tree and make it real in your data structure. And yes, in this case this means a child of the node, where UCB has arrived.

Comment: Thanks. The only thing now that makes me still a bit of noise is, this tree the game defines, is defined for each game the user play with the machine, simulating n plays from that current hand. Somehow with this simulations the machine is some steps ahead thinking of possibilities which is pretty fine, but It will be reseted the next time the player wants to play say another "level" inside the game, isn't it?. How can I think of persist the ia inteligence having in mind that what I'been recording on the tree was based in a different gamestate?

Comment: @magnoz When the "real" game progresses, you can simply assign the corresponding node (which is one step under the current root) the new root and keep all the simulations that correspond to the actually played move. Whether this is a substantial portion depends...

Comment: @ziggystar Why only one new node is added per loop? Each time we hit unexplored actions we need to choose one at random, which is essentially same as rollout. So we can add whole rollout path (up to depth limit) to tree. Or not?

Comment: @MikhailCheshkov That's right. You can also keep the whole rollout path (or parts). It takes more space, and it depends on the problem (depth, branching factor) whether it will be useful or not.